# IE7 Jquery.Each() is not working

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to figure out how this jquery.each() could work on IE 7:

```
        var todosOsCampos = $(".validate_mail");

         jQuery.each(todosOsCampos, function(){
            //Verifica e-mail
            email = $(this).val();
            if(email!=''){
                er = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.)[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2}/;
                if(!er.exec(email)) {
                    erro = 1;
                    $(this).css("border", "solid 1px #F00");
                }   
            }
        });
```

I'm checking the e-mail but on Ie7 is not working properly

I Thought the problem was solved but I was wrong. I've changed the code like the example of user2246674 asked me to do.

```
        var todosOsCampos = $(".validate_mail");

        todosOsCampos.each(function(){
            email = this.value;
            console.log(email);
            if(email!=''){
                er = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.)[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2}/;
                if(!er.exec(email)) {
                    erro = 1;
                    this.style.border = "solid 1px #F00";
                }   
            }
        });
```

But the IE7 is returning the follow message:

> Problem with this web page might prevent it from being displayed
>   properly or functioning properly. In the future...

And then I hit the show details button:

> ```
> Line: 528
> Char: 5
> Error: Object does not support this property or method
> ```
>
> Code: 0

Line 528 correspond to this

> email = this.value;

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider the code suspect - and prone to fail - because the wrong "each" is being used. (But who knows; surprising things can happen.)

There is [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) (e.g. `$.each(array, ..)`), which *is* being used:

> *A generic iterator function*, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays.

And [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) (e.g. `$(selector).each(..)`), which *should* be used:

> *Iterate over a jQuery object*, executing a function for each matched element.

In this case, use `.each` to *iterate over the jQuery object*, such as:

```
todosOsCampos.each(function(){ .. })
```

Remember that `$(selector)` *always* returns a jQuery object which is a collection of 0 or more elements matched.

If problems persist after correcting the usage, update the post with more details including warning/error messages.

Comment: IT SEEMS TO WORKIN FINE RIGHT NOW. It's funny because i've tryied like this:

$.each($(Selector), function(){});
Jquery.each($(Selector),function(){});

None of those options above was the correct syntax for ie7 interpreter.

The funny thing its that, on others interpreters such as Chrome, Firefox and IE > 8 worked perfectly fine.

but thanks.

Comment: No, no, `$(selector).each(..)` and `$.each(array,..)` :) There must be a subtle difference with IE7. Oh well - that's not surprising!